# dropdown select menu loses css style after ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I have a form where the user can choose his country and then depending on the country that is chosen, the dropdown (select) of the form changes to a list of states/provinces of that country. So far so good. The problem is that the dropdown select form is styled with CSS. When the page initially loads, everything is perfect, but when the ajax script is called that then changes the states/provinces dropdown, it returns unstyled, so basically it loses all styling. Does anyone know how to get around this? The code is styled correctly, for some reason it's just not executing it when ajax returns it.

Here is the jquery code:

```
function state_box(country, user_id)
{
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();

    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
            alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
            return;
    }

    var url    = relative_path + 'states.php';
    var action    = url + '?country_id=' + country.value;

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
            {
                    var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
                    document.getElementById('stateBox').innerHTML = response;
            }
    };
    xmlHttp.open("GET", action, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

And the content of states.php, basically just returns the dropdown, nothing fancy:

```
        $display_output = '<select class="mystyle" name="dropdown" id="dropdown"> ';
        $display_output .= '<option value="" selected>Select a State</option> ';

        while ($state_details = $this->fetch_array($sql_select_states))
        {
            $display_output .= '<option value="' . $state_details['id'] . '" ' . (($selected_value == $state_details['id']) ? 'selected' : ''). '>' . $state_details['s.name'] . '</option>';
        }

        $display_output .= '</select>';

    $display_output = ($in_ajax) ? $display_output : '<div id="stateBox">' . $display_output . '</div>';

    return $display_output;
```

The only problem basically is that CSS class "mystyle" is not formatted in the browser after it's returned by ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of generating whole select box in response. Just generate options alone and put it into select box in javascript. Try this,

```
PHP Code :

$display_output = '<option value="" selected>Select a State</option> ';

while ($state_details = $this->fetch_array($sql_select_states))
{
    $display_output .= '<option value="' . $state_details['id'] . '" ' . (($selected_value == $state_details['id']) ? 'selected' : ''). '>' . $state_details['s.name'] . '</option>';
}

return $display_output;
```

And in JAVASCRIPT,

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
            {
                    var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
                    document.getElementById('dropdown').innerHTML = response;
            }
    };
```

It wont affect your CSS and select box also.

But i would suggest you to go with Jquery for future script requirements.

Comment: Wow, that's a fantastic idea! I will give it a try right now :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, I tried it. It's loading fine on the initial load, with the dropdown showing correctly, but when I change the country, it shows the dropdown outputted in something like text format. Basically one line after the other in plain text, without an actual dropdown.

Comment: It should work perfectly. Please check your select box id is correct and you did everything correct

Comment: Yeah, definitely all correct. I can switch between countries and it displays the provinces/states correctly, just in plain text. When I initially load the form, it selects the default country correct with all the states and shows them correctly in the dropdown, just when switched it shows them as plain text list and doesn't go back to being a dropdown. Weird :S

Comment: It's definitely all correct. I double checked the names, divs, etc. The only output being returned now by the ajax is the options with your exact code above. Everything else around it is hard coded into HTML, from the outside div, to the select around the options.

Comment: I think I found what the problem might be with Firefox Firebug. The jquery code replaces the part of the "document.getElementById" with the returned ajax code, right? I see that the "select" part around the options is getting deleted because it's inside the "div" part that is getting replaced. So basically the list is getting output without the select around it.

Comment: I had to change the I'd of the box and it's working. Thank you s much!